# How macOS .app's are executable vs .exe's?

Tags: macos, package, exe

I am a hardcore Windows user, and I know a LOT about Windows. But one thing I still don't really get... how are `.app's` on macOS executable when they are just a folder with that extension, like `.exe's` on Windows?? That's what I don't get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, the `.app` itself is not an executable. It's a standardized folder structure which contains the real executable in one of the subfolders: `Contents/MacOS`. There's also a bunch of metadata and perhaps additional libraries the app needs in several subfolders within `Contents`. The metadata defines the icon, the application name, version number and so on. It is stored in `Contents/Info.plist`. The program on macOS that is responsible for showing you files and folders (Windows Explorer on Windows) is called Finder. Finder simply handles making a folder structure with the `.app` extension and an `Info.plist` present *appear* like a single executable file. There's more examples of folder structures that appear to be files in Finder, for example with `.sparsebundle` Disk Images or the Photo Libraries stored by Apple's Photos app. You can right click those "files" and choose "Show package contents" in Finder to look inside the folder structures.